# Refresh ao clicar na aba (Foundation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

Preciso dar um refresh no conteúdo ao clicar na `aba`. Esse refresh terá  de ser feito na aba Conteúdo 2. Alguém consegue me ajudar.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
            <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">
                <li class="tabs-title is-active">
                    <a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Conteúdo 1</a></li>
                <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel2">Conteúdo 2</a></li>                          
            </ul>
            <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
                <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1">
                    Conteudo1
                </div>
                <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel2">
                    Conteudo2
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) do jQuery, indicando como alvo a mesma página e a `div`. Provavelmente irá combinar com `ajax` de onde irá trazer o novo conteúdo.

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabs-panel" id="panel2">
  Conteudo2
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#panel2').click(function(){
  // faca algo antes
  $('#panel2').load(document.URL +  ' #panel2'); // recarrega a div
});
```

[Foudation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/javascript.html) usa jQuery, por isso na verdade poderá usar `load`.

Comment: Opa blz, não funcionou amigo :/